# Do PSD to XHTML/CSS conversion services yield usable and reliable code?

Tags: css, xhtml, photoshop

Most of us who do any amount of work in web apps/web design have seen ads for PSD to XHTML conversion services.  Provided with a cash outlay and a source PSD file, these services claim to return professional-quality XHTML/CSS within a few days.

Coding up the XHTML/CSS for any project is often the most time consuming portion of the project.  If these services really do produce professional-quality code, then even at a cost of several hundred dollars per page, it would be financially beneficial for me to use them.

So, what's your experience with these services?  Quality code?  Junk?  Cross-browser functionality and graceful degradation?  Etc...

Thanks so much! :)

Comment: It probably wildly differs from junk to decent work. I doubt a general answer is possible.

Comment: @Pekka: Good point.  Nevertheless, even knowing that there are services that do perform decent work is enough promise for me to consider this option more seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be a bit biased being that I come from a front end development background, but I'll say this...

The bottom line is the person who does your front end has to:

A.  Be competent
B.  Give a damn
C.  Take the effort to go through the tedious process of making sure everything is pixel perfect, semantically correct, and engineered to work well with jQuery enhancements.

Do you think that will happen for $99?  Build it yourself or rewrite it later when it becomes an issue and you have to.  A good front end takes planning just like a good back end.

Comment: take into account that 99$ in one country compared to 99$ in another can make for the difference - not everybody is paying their bills in UK or France ;)

Comment: I promise you nobody on cssremix.com is hiring rent-a-coders.

Answer (score 2):

Choose one that makes examples of their work available.  For example, [this company](http://www.psd2html.com) has done good work in my limited experience with them, and makes code samples available: http://www.psd2html.com/examples.html

Based on samples of their work, you can decide for yourself whether or not their work is what you consider usable and reliable.  Otherwise, it's really too subjective a question for us to answer for you.